# How to set gecos attribute in Active Directory using directory services(C#)

Tags: c#, attributes, active-directory, directoryservices

I need to create an user in Active Directory using `System.DirectoryServices`, and I can't figure how to set the `gecos` attribute.

Trying this line simply won't work :

```
DEUtilisateur.Properties["gecos"].Value = gecosValue
```

I get the error :

> The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist

Any tips on how to achieve this?
Thank you

Comment: What version is your Active Directory Server running its database at, `gecos` was not added [till 2003 R2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675715%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). (remember you can run older schemas on newer versions so just because you use 2008 does not mean you are running the 2008 schema.)

Comment: We are using window server 2008 and I'm 100% sure the schemas has gecos because this attributes is already used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the way to access the attribute.

Instead of using directly the DirectoryEntry to connect to the LDAP such as :

`DirectoryEntry DEBase = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + DomaineName);`

I used

```
DirectoryContext context = new DirectoryContext(DirectoryContextType.Domain, 
                    domaineName));

DirectoryEntry dERoot = System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory.Domain.GetDomain(context).GetDirectoryEntry();
```

Then I have no problem accessing the gecos attribute